# Get week starting date from weeknum and year in R

Tags: r, date

I'm looking for a function that will get year + week number + Week day, and return a date, for example:

I would like to input the 3 following

```
 2015
 Monday
 23
```

And get the desired output:

```
"2015-06-08"
```

After Searching in the Web, there seems to be  equivalent question in other languages but not in R:

[How to Get date from week number and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449810/how-to-get-date-from-week-number-and-year)

Any help on that would be great!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `strptime`:

```
strptime("2015Monday23", "%Y%A%U")
# [1] "2015-06-08"
```

Or more generally

```
strptime(paste0(2015, "Monday", 23), "%Y%A%U")
```

Comment: `strptime` is returning the same classes/attributes as `as.POSIXlt`. Though I forgot about `A`, so nice one there.

Comment: Be careful with ISO dates where the isoyear != year (can occur on first / last week of the year, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week)

Answer (score 1):

There are two caveats here:

1. The result depends on the current locale.
   In my locale `"German_Germany.1252"` (call `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` to check your locale), `strptime("2015Monday23", "%Y%A%U")` returns `NA`.
2. The results depends on the convention for numbering the weeks of a year.
   There are 3 conventions `R` is aware of: US, UK, and ISO 8601. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587644/3817004) for a detailed discussion. So, the convention to be used for conversion has to be specified.

#### Non-English locales

If you are in a non-english locale, you can deal with English weekday names (or month names, likewise) by temporarily changing the current locale:

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "US")
#> [1] "English_United States.1252"
strptime("2015Monday23", "%Y%A%U")
#> [1] "2015-06-08 CEST"
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME")
#> [1] "German_Germany.1252"
```

The `lubridate` package offers a more convenient way:

```r
lubridate::parse_date_time("2015Monday23", "YAU", locale = "US")
#> [1] "2015-06-08 UTC"
```

#### Week of the year in different conventions

As the weekday is given by its name, the US and UK conventions return the same result:

```r
lubridate::parse_date_time("2015Monday23", "YAU", locale = "US")
#> [1] "2015-06-08 UTC"
lubridate::parse_date_time("2015Monday23", "YAW", locale = "UK")
#> [1] "2015-06-08 UTC"
```

Unfortunately, the format specifiers for the ISO 8601 convention are not accepted on input. So, we reverse the process and format the resulting date as week of the year in the different conventions which shows a differing result for ISO 8601.

```r
format(as.Date("2015-06-08 UTC"), "%Y-%W-%u") # UK convention
#> [1] "2015-23-1"
format(as.Date("2015-06-08 UTC"), "%Y-%U-%w") # US convention
#> [1] "2015-23-1"
format(as.Date("2015-06-08 UTC"), "%G-%V-%u") # ISO 8601
#> [1] "2015-24-1"
```