# How to get week starting date from a date in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a dataset with a column containing dates. I want to find the week starting dates for those `date` values.

I get the week number using `week` function from `lubridate`.
For example,

```
week(as.Date("04/20/2017", "%m/%d/%Y"))

#Solution
[1] 16
```

Instead of `weeknum`, is there a way to get the starting date of the week? In this case I am expecting either "04/16/2017" or "04/17/2017". I am not very particular if the week starts from Sunday or Monday.
I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776575/get-week-starting-date-from-weeknum-and-year-in-r) question, but didn't get much from it.

Comment: Another way, with data.table: `round(as.IDate("04/20/2017", "%m/%d/%Y"), "week")`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `floor_date` function from the `lubridate` package.

```
library("lubridate")
floor_date(as.Date("04/20/2017", "%m/%d/%Y"), unit="week")
```

Comment: Make you add `library(lubridate)` before running `floor_date`

Comment: worth mentioning that can also force the week to start on a Monday with `floor_date(x, unit = 'week', week_start = 1)` ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use below

```
as.Date(format(as.Date("04/20/2017", "%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y-%W-1"),"%Y-%W-%u")
[1] "2017-04-17"
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's an issue with how `format` works or just its use here, but this doesn't work for all dates; for example, `as.Date(format(as.Date("01/04/2019", "%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y-%W-1"),"%Y-%W-%u")` returns `NA` because `format(as.Date("01/04/2019", "%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y-%W-1")` returns `"2019-00-1"`.