# Week/year format as date in R

Tags: r, date, posixct

I have a data set `dat` with a `year` and a `week` variable (both integers). I want to combine them into a `date` `POSIXct` variable in `R` of the format W-YYYY.

However, I get NA values when I use the `as.POSIXct` function.

My code is below:

```
as.POSIXct(paste(dat$week, dat$year), format="%V-%Y")
```

Comment: I do not think a weeknumber can represent a posixct, since it is a period

Comment: The date formats require complete data. You need to atleast include a dummy weekday

Comment: A value of class `Date` or `POSIXct` does not have a "format". A particular format will only be used when converting to character, e.g., for printing.

Comment: There are different definitions of how to number the weeks of a year. Which one do you want to use? `%V` refers to week numbering according to ISO8601 but `%Y` to the calendar year. In ISO8601 week numbering, the year may differ from the calendar year. The ISO8601 week numbering is referred by `%G`.

Comment: Please, see these answers for more details: [Transform year/week to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587644/3817004), [Get week starting date from weeknum and year in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720354/3817004)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you'll want the first monday of the given week? If you want an other day, change the value of %u accordingly.

```
yr = 2018
wk = 10
as.POSIXct( paste( 1, wk, yr, sep = "-" ), format = "%u-%U-%Y" )
[1] "2018-03-12 CET"
```

Comment: Are you aware that there are three different definitions of how to count week of the year?